# Pass fragment as parameter?

Tags: java, android, generics, android-fragments

I have simple method where I want to pass fragment name as parameter.
I have few fragments like

1) AddNewDatesFragment

2) AskFragment

3) DisclaimerFragment

I have below code that work properly as expected

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();     entry++) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)    fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry);
        if (fragment instanceof AddNewDatesFragment) {
            Log.i("TAG", " Expected Fragment Found");
        }
    }
```

I want to write some code in method where I could call methods like this

```
        isExistFragment(AddNewDatesFragment);
        isExistFragment(AskFragment);
        isExistFragment(DisclaimerFragment);
```

etc...

I have tried code like this but not working gives compile time error at if condition.

```
    private boolean isExistFragment(Class<Fragment> expectedFragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (int entry = 0; entry < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry);
        if (fragment instanceof expectedFragment) {
            Log.i("TAG", " Expected Fragment Found");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I am curious about implementing such method. 
Thanks,

Comment: compile time error at which line in the flowing code..

Comment: at if condition as : Multiple markers at this line
 - expectedFragment cannot be resolved to a type
 - Incompatible conditional operand types Fragment and 
  expectedFragment

Comment: Fragment Return null : in this line : Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentManager
                 .findFragmentById(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry)
                         .getId());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether it is the best way or not. But I would use *tag* feature for the similar purpose.

When you add a fragment set a tag for later identification:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.container, newlyAddFragment, TAG_FOR_THE_FRAGMENT)
               .commit();
```

And implement *isExistFragment* like this:

```
boolean isExistFragment(String tag) {
    Fragment targetFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
    return targetFragment != null;
}
```

Comment: Yes its work for me too, At last I used the same strategy to solved theissue.

Answer (score 1):

```
getBackStackEntryAt(index)
```

does not return Fragment itself, it return BackStackEntry object for the respected fragment.

Please have a look http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#getBackStackEntryAt(int)

Use below snippet to retrieve Fragment from the stack:

```
   Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(entry)
                    .getId());
```

Here, first you get BackStackEntry for the respected Fragement, by which you would get fragment id of fragment at perticular location.
Then by id you easily can retrieve Fragment.

Comment: But I am getting compile time error, as you say that thing only comes at runtime.

Comment: use reflection : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846853/passing-a-class-as-an-argument-to-a-method-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use:

```
expectedFragment.isAssignableFVrom(fragment.getClass())
```

This will be `true` if the `exceptedFragment` class is an interface or superclass of the `fragment` class (see [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))).

(PS: you can not use `fragment instanceof expectedFragment` on `exceptedFragment` because it is a class and not an object.)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem with the import statements in the class extends FragmentActivity you imported supportv4 and in that expectedFragment you imported "import android.app.Fragment" once check import statements.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

or
    import android.app.Fragment;